# Wi-Fi issues with Debian 9 (non-free drivers not working(?))

Tags: debian, wifi

I have an HP pavilion 15 model j9h21ua, and a fresh install of Debian 9. I'm very new to Debian, but I figured out how to get non-free drivers working.

Despite this, I can't seem to locate my network driver in lsusb or lspci -nn, which makes it kinda hard to figure out what drivers to install. I tried some kernel thing posted earlier, and some other driver fixes to no avail. I may try reinstalling regardless because I'm not exactly sure what I did to it, but I'd like to be able to use the wireless functionality on my laptop!

Here is  the lspci -nn printout:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex [1022:1536]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series] [1002:9830]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio [1002:9840]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0 [1022:1538]
00:02.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1 [1022:1439]
00:02.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1 [1022:1439]
00:10.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7814] (rev 01)
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7804]
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 39)
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 39)
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:780b] (rev 3a)
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:780e] (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0 [1022:1530]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1 [1022:1531]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2 [1022:1532]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3 [1022:1533]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4 [1022:1534]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5 [1022:1535]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
```

and here's the lsusb printout:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05c8:0226 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

According to partsurfer.hp.com, it would be a Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bg/n 1x1 WiFi adapter.

Since it's a PCIe device, it really should be visible in the `lspci` listing, regardless of any WiFi driver. Perhaps the ACPI firmware implements a radio kill-switch? Try pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, or the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> key combination.

According to [this manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03939658), there might be a WiFi indicator light integrated into the <kbd>F12</kbd> key or near it. Is it lit? Is it lit up amber, or some other (unspecified) color? Does it change if you use the above-mentioned key/combination? If you can make it change, check the `lspci` listing again after changing the state of the WiFi indicator light.

If that does not help, or the <kbd>F12</kbd> key is unresponsive, you might need a model-specific RF-kill driver. Unfortunately, implementing such a driver might require some reverse engineering on the hardware, unless HP would kindly make the hardware programming documentation available to Linux developers.